# Endless loop in Spring MVC Interceptor

Tags: spring, interceptor

I have written a custom interceptor **PreventScreenInterceptor** extends **HandlerInterceptorAdapter**

in **preHandle** I am checking some conditions, and based on that, I am redirecting using

```
response.sendRedirect("/myapp/user/noaccess");
```

Now, whenever I am hitting **/myapp/user/noaccess** , it is going into endless loop as I am not able to come out of this interceptor. Its getting called again and again.

My Application context has :

```
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/myapp/user/**"/>
        <bean class="com.mypackage.interceptors.PreventScreenInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

Comment: Please add some context. Is your `HandlerInterceptor` intercepting requests to `/myapp/user/noaccess`? Does it then re-redirect to `/myapp/user/noaccess`?

Comment: Yes, HandlerInterceptor is intercepting requests for that URL. Edited question to include more details. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `request.getRequestURI()` to check that the URI being called is not "/myapp/user/noaccess", before sending your redirect.

Comment: It works. Thank you..but is there any other clean way to achieve the same purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

You must check that the if the request is not coming with the action where you are redirecting from Interceptor , otherwise it will recall itself again and again.

for reference use this code -

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,

    HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        logger.debug("inside interceptor  and uri = "+uri);

        if (!uri.endsWith("/noaccess") ) {
            logger.info("request is coming from other than /myapp/user/noaccess");
            response.sendRedirect("/myapp/user/noaccess");
        }

        return true;
    }
```